# How can I target specific data frames based on pattern matching using Regex?

Tags: r, regex, list, dataframe

I have several data frames and I want to merge specific ones into a list for easier management.

As there are lots of data frames, I am using `lapply()` to perform the merge quickly.

My pattern matching (regex) element looks like this:

```
ls(pattern = "jan[0-9]")
```

which returns:

```
[1] "jan0000"      "jan0000_0059" "jan0100"      "jan0100_0159" "jan0200"      "jan0200_0259" "jan0300"      "jan0300_0359" "jan0400"      "jan0400_0459" "jan0500"
[12] "jan0500_0559" "jan0600"      "jan0600_0659" "jan0700"      "jan0700_0759" "jan0800"      "jan0800_0859" "jan0900"      "jan0900_0959" "jan1000"      "jan1000_1059"
[23] "jan1100"      "jan1100_1159" "jan1200"      "jan1200_1259" "jan1300"      "jan1300_1359" "jan1400"      "jan1400_1459" "jan1500"      "jan1500_1559" "jan1600"
[34] "jan1600_1659" "jan1700"      "jan1700_1759" "jan1800"      "jan1800_1859" "jan1900"      "jan1900_1959" "jan2000"      "jan2000_2059" "jan2100"      "jan2100_2159"
[45] "jan2200"      "jan2200_2259" "jan2300"      "jan2300_2359"
```

However, the problem is that I only want to extract the data frames whose names are 12 characters in length.

I have tried numerous things like searching for an exact length (the ones I am interested in are all the same length):

```
ls(pattern = "jan[0-9]{12}")
```

but it returns:

```
character(0)
```

Another way I think would work would be to search for anything that begins with `jan`, followed by four numbers and then an underscore.  The problem is that I can't seem to get the regex expression to return any results.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Try `ls(pattern = "^jan[0-9]{4}_")`

Comment: Perfect! Please post this as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may use

```
ls(pattern = "^jan[0-9]{4}_")
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `jan` - a literal substring
- `[0-9]{4}` -  any four ASCII digits
- `_` - an underscore.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XCr0tx/1).

If you append `[0-9]{4}$` you will restrict the pattern further to require 4 digits and end of string to the right of the underscore. See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XCr0tx/2).